# TextBox bound to brush not updating UI despite calling OnPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I will use a simplified version of my classes to avoid including too much information. I have this class extending Canvas set as DataContext in Main Window and it writes "Hello world" using Formatted Text with the color of the property textBrush. I have a TextBox and want to be able to change that color through it, however my UI is not updating when the property is?

```
public class CanvasExtension: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

   private SolidColorBrush textBrush

        public SolidColorBrush TextBrush
        {
            get { return textBrush; }
            set
            {
                textBrush= value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            base.OnRender(dc);
            FormattedText formattedTextInput = new FormattedText("Hello world",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
                FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface("Verdana"), 12, TextBrush, 1);
                dc.DrawText(formattedTextInput, 0);

        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
```

Main Window code:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
          InitializeComponent();
          this.DataContext = visualTable;
        }

        private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
          if (e.Key==Key.Enter)
          {
            TextBox box = (TexBox)sender;
            DependencyProperty property = TextBox.TextProperty;

            BindingExpression binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(box,property);
            if (binding != null)
            {
              binding.UpdateSource();
            }
            KeyBoard.ClearFocus();

          }

        }
    }
```

And finally, my Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="DrawingTutorial.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

        <Grid>
         <local:CanvasExtension x:Name="visualTable">  </local:CanvasExtension>
             <TextBox Text="{Binding TextBrush}"></TextBox>
        </Grid>





</Window>
```

What I want to achieve  (and I thought should work) is following: I enter some color in the textBox and I press enter. Then, the TextBrush property is updated, and here because I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and throw the event in the setter, my UI should update ( be redrawn? I don't know if it is the same in the case of a canvas ) and I should see "Hello World" written with the new color. This however is not happening ( the bindings work, I checked ) until I explicitly call InvalidateVisual(), which I believe beats the purpose of INotifyPropertyChanged. Is there a way to do that without having to manually reset the visual?
Note, if I add InvalidateVisual() in the setter after calling OnPropertyChanged(); it updates the UI, the functionality that I need. However, isn't the UI supposed to update exactly because I am calling OnPropertyChanged() and the program "knows" that it has to update?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you bind a Brush object to a string property? Also what is visualTable?

Comment: Apologies, visualTable is an instance of my CanvasExtension, but I had accidentally written <local:CanvasExtensionx:Name>, edited it. I bound brush to TextBox and it works correctly, I believe, namely: TextBox displayed the hexadecimal color of brush, and upon editing TextBox, Brush color value changes. This happens when I bind it to brush directly. My problem is that it is not updating the UI unless I explicitly call for it, despite calling OnPropertyChanged()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You must give your `CanvasExtension` control a size greater than 0 to provide an area to draw on. Either configure the `Grid` rows properly to allow the control to stretch and to prevent the `TextBox` from covering the `CanvasExtension` or set `CanvasExtension.Width` and `CanvasExtension.Height` explicitly.
2. Since `CanvasExtension` is a `DependencyObject` (it extends `Canvas`), you should implement properties as `DependencyProperty` instead of implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This will improve the performance (and add other benefits).
3. Because you draw text in `UIElement.OnRender`, you would have to call `UIElement.InvalidateVisual` to force rendering i.e. the invocation of `UIElement.OnRender` on property changes.
   When implementing the `CanvasExtension.TextBrush` property as `DependencyProperty`, as suggested in 2), you can configure the property to force the invocation of `UIElement.OnRender` by setting the `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender` flag on the property meta data. This is more elegant.
4. Either set the `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` to `UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit` and update the `Binding.Source` manually (as you did) or simply move the focus away from the `TextBox` (recommended). The default `Binding.Mode` of the `TextBox.Text` property is `BindingMode.LostFocus`. So moving away the focus produces the shortest and simplest code.

**CanvasExtension.cs**

```cs
public class CanvasExtension : Canvas
{
  public SolidColorBrush TextBrush
  {
    get => (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(TextBrushProperty);
    set => SetValue(TextBrushProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "TextBrush",
    typeof(SolidColorBrush),
    typeof(CanvasExtension),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
      default(SolidColorBrush), 
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
    
  protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
  {
    base.OnRender(dc);
    FormattedText formattedTextInput = new FormattedText(
      "Hello world", 
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
      FlowDirection.LeftToRight, 
      new Typeface("Verdana"), 
      12, 
      this.TextBrush, 
      1);
    dc.DrawText(formattedTextInput, new Point(0, 0));
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    switch (e.Key)
    {
      // Update TextBox.Text binding
      case Key.Enter:
        (sender as FrameworkElement).MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));  
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <local:CanvasExtension x:Name="visualTable"
                           Height="200"
                           Width="200" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

    <TextBox PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" 
             Text="{Binding ElementName=visualTable, Path=TextBrush}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write it in the constructor, but in my class I have Width and Height set to 500. Regarding your third point, is there a reason why I have to call it explicitly, despite calling OnPropertyChanged() that updates the UI? Or are the things drawn on the canvas not a part of the UI? Regarding the fourth point, am I not changin the focus by calling Keyboard.ClearFocus() or is keyboard focus not enough? It worked for some of my other textboxes so I am genuinely curious

Comment: OnPropertyChanged will only update a date binding (the binding from the property that the Property changed event is raised from). But you are drawing in OnRender. WPF will only call this method when InvalidateVisual was called. The Property changed works on data binding level and OnRender on rendering level. They are not related. A  property change will only result in a rendering process when the control (the binding target) explicitly requests it - what you must do. Or when the layout system detects changes e.g. the size or brushes of a control.

Comment: Keyboard.ClearFocus() will only remove the keyboard focus. WPF distinguishes between logical focus and keyboard focus. Losing keyboard focus does not necessarily result in losing the logical focus. But you need to clear the logical focus to trigger the LostFocus event so that the TextBox.Text binding can update and send the input to the binding source.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, I didn't know that the logical focus hat to be removed as well. Have a great day :)